# Can we load dynamic library during linking?

Tags: c++, linker, dynamic-library

I need to include `Security32.dll` windows library into my project. Of course, I can load this library dynamically with [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx) function, but is it possible to link the library during linking? I mean something like this (The following example is not correct, I just tried that and provide it as an example):

```
g++ -o bin main.o -lsecurity.dll
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really depends on your actual linker.

The GCC toolchain provided as part of the MinGW project will allow you to use dynamic link libraries (dll files) directly under Windows rather than static libraries only (or MSVC's lib files), but you'll still need the proper header files so the compiler knows what to call.

Microsoft Visual C++ on the other hand won't support this and will always need static libraries (lib files) with the proper information, even when you're linking against a dynamic/shared library.

Comment: I'm on cygwin and using ld linker which is a part of it.

Comment: Well, yes we can link so-library with gcc, and I'm interested in wheteher there is something similar for dll.

Comment: Cygwin is just another port of GCC, so the same applies.

Comment: @user3663882 When using the GCC toolchain (no matter whether it's MinGW or cygwin) the same applies to Windows. Just don't rely on everyone being able to do so as it depends on the toolchain being used.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example for cygwin, I really don;t understand how it ever depends on header files

Comment: @user3663882 Your compiler has to know the signature of functions you'd like to call. So you'll need the proper header files. This will then create a unsatisfied reference to an external function, which the linker will pick up and try to solve given the libraries passed as input (in your example: Security32.dll). If your program compiles fine, your headers are fine as well (typically the case for standard WinAPI stuff).

Comment: Yes, but linker don't know what library contains the definition of an actual function, even if we include a corresponding header file. As you said, it just contains declarations, not definitions. So it should throw an error. When I was writing a winsok client application I explicitly specify a library as follows `g++ -o bin main.cpp -lws2_32`. Otherwise the linker just printed an error.

Comment: @user3663882 It's possible to enumerate all public functions in a library. The linker will just go through all libraries you've provided and pick the first match (no matter whether it's static or dynamic). Your example command line should be fine and link properly.

Comment: It seems you don't understand what I don't understand :). I don't know how I can provide `Security32.dll` for the linker.

Comment: @user3663882 Exactly the way you did. Just use `-lSecurity32.dll`. Just keep in mind the linker has to find it, so you might have to provide the proper path as well (using `-L`).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'd like to clarify about -L option in cygwin. I should pass an absolute cygwin-like path (e.g. `/cygdrive/c/path/to/lib/Security.32.dll`) or what?

Comment: @user3663882 It may be absolute or relative, that's your choice.